# How do I start a CoffeeScript repl from within a CoffeeScript script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, read-eval-print-loop

If I do

```
repl = require 'repl'

repl.start {useGlobal: true}
```

It starts a Node repl.  How do I start a CoffeeScript repl instead?

Thanks

Comment: http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/repl.html

Comment: That's what I ended up doing but I thought there would be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nesh is a project to try and make this a bit easier and extensible:

http://danielgtaylor.github.com/nesh/

It provides a way to embed a REPL with support for multiple languages like CoffeeScript as well as providing an asyncronous plugin architecture, support to execute code in the context of the REPL on startup, etc. For example:

```
nesh = require 'nesh'

nesh.loadLanguage 'coffee'

nesh.start (err, repl) ->
    nesh.log.error err if err
```

It also supports a bunch of options with the default plugins and exposes some built-in convenience functions as well:

```
opts =
    welcome: 'Welcome to my interpreter!'
    prompt: '> '
    evalData: CoffeeScript.compile 'hello = (name="world") -> "Hello, #{world}!"', {bare: true}

nesh.start opts, (err, repl) ->
    nesh.log.error err if err
```

Comment: Nice to see you here, Daniel. Now i understand where the motivation for the Coffee REPL enhancements come from =D

Comment: On first attempt, looks like the nesh REPL has none of the running context attached to it (in node.js) when it launches its REPL using the first code snippet of this answer. Anything that can make it launch with the context of where it's launched from?

Comment: @matt there is a fix for nesh that is ready to go but it's pending an upstream CoffeeScript release. See here: https://github.com/danielgtaylor/nesh/issues/4#issuecomment-22157603

Answer (score 5):

I think the `coffee-script` module does not export the REPL functionality to be used programmatically, like the Node `repl` module does. But CoffeeScript has a [`repl.coffee`](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/src/repl.coffee) file that can be used, even though it's not exported in the main `coffee-script` module. Taking [a hint from `command.coffee`](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/ace4837365447c665c56975ae7080029cbd78d53/src/command.coffee#L75) (which is the file that's executed when you run the `coffee` command) we can see that the REPL works just by requiring the `repl` file. So, running this script should start a CoffeeScript REPL:

```
require 'coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/repl'
```

This approach, however, is *quite hacky*. The most important flaw is that it heavily depends on how the `coffee-script` module works internally and how it's organized. Nothing prevents the `repl.coffee` file from being moved from `coffee-script/lib/coffee-script`, or changing the way it works.

A better approach might be calling the `coffee` command without arguments, just like one would do from the commandline, from Node:

```
{spawn} = require 'child_process'
spawn 'coffee', [], stdio: 'inherit'
```

The [`stdio: 'inherit'` option](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) makes the spawned command to read from stdin and write to the stdout of the current process.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I'll still have to require the file since I'm trying to allow access to the current process variables.

Comment: @Nick, i'm glad it helped :). My understanding is that `stdio: 'inherit'` just makes the spawned process use the same stdin and stdout as the process that spawned it, but it will be a new process (process.pid will be different for example). If my answer is not what you were looking for, maybe you can expand the question by explaining what you're trying to accomplish with the REPL itself.

Comment: the second approach loses all the current environment (i.e. the variables) so it's almost pointless :/

Comment: I think I'd rather write a function that compiles coffeescript to javascript, and pipes the output to an eval statement. Then I can run it in the javascript repl for (at least) one-liner coffeescript code snippets.

Comment: I previously tried @epidemian's approach, like so: adding that require (e.g. `coffeeRepl = require 'coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/repl'`, running node.js via `coffee --nodejs debug`, adding a `debugger` statement in my coffeescript code, and when the debugger stops there, first invoking the node.js javascript repl via `repl`... but then naively invoking the coffeescript repl from the javascript repl via `coffeeRepl.start()` falls back to the javascript repl immediately without waiting for input... maybe the coffeescript repl invocation should be made a little differently for it to work (?)

Comment: Now there is a path 'coffee-script/repl.js', which requires the 'coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/repl.js' file. Since they put this file on the top directory, allowing us to do a require("coffee-script/repl"), probably it should be taken as some external interface instead of depending on the package internals. Therefore, I would use the later.